# formatting string into dateformat with time offset

Tags: java, jodatime

I need to convert a string into a `Joda` `DateTime` object, but the code I am using is not doing the conversion correct.  My input is `20140722101846-0700`, which should convert to something not unlike `2014-07-22T10:18:46-0700`.  Here is my code, followed by the incorrect output:

```
String myet = "20140722101846-0700"
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyyMMddhhmmss-hhmm");
DateTime mydt = dtf.parseDateTime(myet);
```

The resulting (incorrect) output is:  `2014-07-22T07:00:46.000-07:00`

How can I fix the code above so that is outputs a correct date?

Comment: Look at the SimpleDateFormat javadoc. Your format symbols are incorrect.

Comment: Right out of the bat ....Don't confuse `m` (minutes) vs `M` (month)

Comment: Perhaps `yyyyMMddhhmmssZ`

Comment: @gtgaxiola Your suggestion works correctly.  Thank you.  If you submit it as an answer, I will mark it as the accepted answer and +1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your DateTimeFormat doesn't have the correct symbols.

`M` is for month

`m` is for minutes

`Z` is used for the time zone offset (-0700)

```
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyyMMddhhmmssZ");
```